# How to persist filterdata when sorting ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a table that has searching, sorting, and filtering (any number of available filters). When I sort the filters get overwritten and I'm not sure how to make sure they stay in the querystring since they are stored in the model as an array of strings.

I've tried using the ViewBag and the asp-route-varName tag but it didn't work since it's an array. I thought since they are all in the same form that they should just append to the querystring not overwrite it. The sort and search works since search is just a string. The filter and search works not entirely sure why.

View:

```
@model ScenarioLake.Api.Host.WebApplication.Models.MasterModel;


<form asp-controller="FileList" asp-action="Index" method="get">

    <p>
        Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
        <a asp-action="Index">Full List</a>
    </p>

    <select class="chosen-select" multiple="multiple" name="filters" asp-for="filters"
            asp-items="Model.filterModel.filters[0].values;"></select>
    <input type="submit" />

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <a asp-controller="FileList" asp-action="Index" asp-route-searchString="@Model.searchString" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.files.FirstOrDefault().Name)
                    </a>                 
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.files)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Guid">Edit</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Guid">Details</a> |
                        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Guid">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Model:

```
public class MasterModel
    {
        public FilterFileModel filterModel { get; set;}
        public List<FileDisplay> files;
        public string[] filters { get; set; }
        public string searchString { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller Index Method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString, MasterModel model)
        {
            ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            IGetFileListHandler fileListHandler = _restServiceFactory.CreateGetFileListHandler();
            GetFileListRequest fileListRequest = new GetFileListRequest();
            IGetFileListResponse response = await fileListHandler.ProcessRequest(fileListRequest);
            var items = new List<FileDisplay>();

            IGetFileAttributesHandler fileAttributesHandler = _restServiceFactory.CreateGetFileAttributesHandler();
            GetFileAttributesRequest fileAttributesRequest = new GetFileAttributesRequest();
            IGetFileAttributesResponse fileAttributesResponse = await fileAttributesHandler.ProcessRequest(fileAttributesRequest);

            IGetFileFileAttributeHandler fileFileAttributesHandler = _restServiceFactory.CreateGetFileFileAttributeHandler();
            GetFileFileAttributeRequest fileFileAttributesRequest = new GetFileFileAttributeRequest();
            IGetFileFileAttributeResponse fileFileAttributesResponse = await fileFileAttributesHandler.ProcessRequest(fileFileAttributesRequest);
            var fileFileAttribute = fileFileAttributesResponse.FileFileAttributes;
            IEnumerable<Entities.Public.Interfaces.IFile> responseFilteredFiles = response.Files;

            FilterFileModel fileFilter = new FilterFileModel();
            fileFilter.filters = new List<FileFilter>();

            if (!ReferenceEquals(fileAttributesResponse, null) && !ReferenceEquals(fileAttributesResponse.Values, null))
            {
                fileFilter.types = fileAttributesResponse.Values.Select(s => s.Type).Distinct().ToList(); // query fileattribute repo to get all types of filters 
                foreach (var type in fileFilter.types)
                {
                    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter();
                    filter.type = type;
                    filter.values = fileAttributesResponse.Values.Where(s => s.Type == type).Select(s => new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Value = s.Value,
                        Text = s.Value
                    }).Distinct().ToList();
                    fileFilter.filters.Add(filter);
                }
            }

            if (!ReferenceEquals(response, null) && !ReferenceEquals(response.Files, null))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    responseFilteredFiles = responseFilteredFiles.Where(s => s.FileName.Contains(searchString));
                    model.searchString = searchString;
                }

                switch(sortOrder)
                {
                    case "name_desc":
                        responseFilteredFiles = responseFilteredFiles.OrderByDescending(s => s.FileName);
                        break;
                    default:
                        responseFilteredFiles = responseFilteredFiles.OrderBy(s => s.FileName);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (model.filters != null)
            {
                if (model.filters.Length != 0)
                {
                    IEnumerable<int> attributeIds = fileAttributesResponse.Values.Where(s => model.filters.Contains(s.Value)).Select(s => s.FileAttributeId);
                    IEnumerable<int> fileIds = fileFileAttribute.Where(s => attributeIds.Contains(s.FileAttributeId)).Select(s => s.FileId);
                    responseFilteredFiles = responseFilteredFiles.Where(s => fileIds.Contains(s.FileId));
                }
            }

            foreach (var item in responseFilteredFiles)
            {
                var file = new FileDisplay()
                {
                    Name = item.FileName,
                    Guid = item.Guid,
                    FileId = item.FileId
                };
                items.Add(file);
            }

            model.filterModel = fileFilter;
            model.files = items;
            return View(model);
        }
```

The expected result is that the filter and search data persists when a user changes the sort. The actual results are only the search persists, I don't care about the sort persisting when the filters or search are changed.